# How to create/add repeated code in vbd editor, not save in personal work book

Tags: excel, vba

Tried several kinds of questions to search but nothing comes up yet.

I saw a website that this person designs an auto generator for VBA codes. I don't need that much of amount of codes. I just need a few lines that I constantly use. 
Where can I start build my own modules in Excel vba editor?

Really appreciate if you have any idea.

[image]

Comment: That screenshot looks like a VBE add-in of some sort. Writing one isn't difficult, but it isn't trivial either. If you have VB6 kicking around, that would probably be more familiar to a VBA programmer, but I'd suggest .NET instead - [this link](https://www.mztools.com/articles/2012/MZ2012013.aspx) is a good starting point.

Comment: No longer free but IMHO worth it: https://www.mztools.com/

Comment: I second the MZ-Tools recommendation. Can also have common code bloacks across a team.

Comment: @Comintern So that it's like to purchase the license for using the library. I'll take a look into that. Thx. man